# Using Silex Firewall in SecurityServiceProvider with {_locale}

Tags: security, internationalization, routes, silex

When I configure Silex `SecurityServiceProvider` to work with `{_locale}` param, `login.check_path` returns a `LogicException` as follow:

> **LogicException**: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Following is my settings:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider, [
    'security.firewalls' => [
        'login' => [
            'pattern' => '^/{_locale}/login',
            'security' => false,
        ],
        'games' => [
            'pattern' => '^/{_locale}/modules/',
            'form' => [
                'login_path' => '/{_locale}/login',
                'check_path' => '/{_locale}/modules/login_check',
            ],
            'logout' => [
                'logout_path' => '/{_locale}/modules/logout',
            ],
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
]);
```

`login_path` and firewall handling seem to work fine, but can't finalize login process.
What's wrong with it?

I also ask you what's the correct route name of `login_path`, `check_path` and `logout_path` to serve to Twig `{{ path() }}` method, as I can't figure it out due to `{_locale}` presence.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today :) and found this solution:

add `default_target_path` and `always_use_default_target_path` to your `security.firewalls` form config.

```
'form' => array(
    'login_path' => '/',
    'check_path' => 'login_check',
    'default_target_path' => '/' . $app['locale'],
    'always_use_default_target_path' => true
),
```

## Edit

So using `$app['locale']` doesn't work well.

It's better you use `$app['session']->get('locale')` and set locale to session in a `before` middleware

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $app['session']->set('locale', $app['locale']);
    ....
});
```

Maybe somebody has a better solution by overloading event listeners. But I think this is a quick solution.

Comment: I know `$app['session']->get('locale')` workaround but it doesn't seem to fix the actual problem of handling (see _check_path_) localized login form based on URL, in the attempt to adhere to URI principles.